# Query Execution Plan for MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

In Microsoft SQL Server you can see Execution Plans for queries to see how a query is executed, what joins take the most time and see any missing indexs

now i want to do the same for MySQL scripts that run on a MySQL Server, i am wondering what programs or tools i can uses for this

EDIT: we have MySQL 5.5 running on Wamp and the development server so we can't use EXPLAIN

Comment: This should be asked in [http://dba.stackexchange.com] (which I didn't see in the list while trying to flag this as off-topic), but did you take a look at the MySQL manual, it contains nidce information with the exact phrase you're using?

Comment: @zagrimsan there's `EXPLAIN` however from what i've read it's really only used for `SELECT` queries, that's good if all i did was `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` however i also have alot of `UPDATE` queries i want checked out aswell

Comment: You seem to need MySQL 5.6 or later for that.

Comment: @zagrimsan that's why i'am asking for any programs or tools i could use

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. You'd much better off asking this in dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: And if you knew in the first place that what you need is available in a more recent version but upgrading is not an option, you should state it in your question (showing that you've done some research yourself prior to asking is worth always).

Comment: @zagrimsan sorry, I worked my response wrong, I asked on dba and that's where I learned that 5.6 could use explain on UPDATE, I forgot to update the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a detailed plan for your query using **Query Profiler** feature of SQLyog.
It gives detailed description about query execution and shows **Explain** plan.
[image]